# How program interpreter locates the full path of dynamic libraries to be loaded?

Tags: c, dynamic-linking

I was trying out dynamic linking of libraries. This is a toy program I wrote:

```
// prog.c

#include<stdio.h>

int sum(int, int);
int diff(int, int);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int a = 10, b = 5;
    
    printf("Sum: %d\n", sum(a, b));
    printf("Diff: %d\n", diff(a, b));
}
```

```
// sum.c

int sum(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

```
// diff.c

int diff(int a, int b) {
    return a - b;
}
```

Compiled using these commands:

```
$ gcc -fPIC -c sum.c diff.c
$ gcc -shared -o libdtest.so sum.o diff.o
$ gcc prog.c -L. -l dtest
```

When I tried to run this, it says `./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libdtest.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. The file libdtest.so is still in my folder. What is the mistake here?

I used readelf to read a.out file. There, in the dynamic section, linked libraries were libdtest.so and libc.so.6 . But I couldn't find any reference to their full paths. How does program interpreter locate those files and load them?

Comment: Are you sure that you are using a C interpreter?

Comment: @Yunnosch it's not C interpreter. By program interpreter, I meant the exec which loads all dynamic libraries required for my program. I don't know what you call them in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dynamic library loader have a fixed set of paths that it uses to search for libraries. If you have a custom library which isn't in that set then the library won't be found and you get an error.

Unfortunately the linker doesn't automatically add the path to the libraries it links with by default to the finished executable. Instead you must specify a special option to add the path: `-rpath`.

You can't use `-rpath` directly with the `gcc` front-end program, it's a linker-specific option. You need to use the `-Wl` option:

```
$ gcc prog.c -L. -l dtest -Wl,-rpath=$PWD
```

If the library is or will be installed in some directory other than `$PWD`, then you need to provide the actual (full) path to the installation directory.

---

Other possible solution includes adding the path to the set the dynamic loader uses (not recommended for uncommon paths), or setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable (which is not recommended at all).

Comment: >Dynamic library loader have a fixed set of paths. Can I inspect them?

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB [man ld.so](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html). Also read `man ldconfig`

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB I've edited this answer -- using `-Wl,-rpath=.` is also a very bad idea.

Comment: @EmployedRussian When I tested, if I used `-rpath=.`, it would be registered as `.` itself (and not the absolute path of current directory). Hence in this case also you can move exec-lib pair freely as long as they are in same folder.

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB You don't understand. If your library is located in say `/tmp`, the binary will run correctly _only_ if your current directory is also `/tmp`. If you `cd $HOME; /tmp/a.out` it will look for the library in `$HOME` and would fail.